# unable to deploy POJO from sar in JBoss 6.1

Tags: java, jboss, pojo, sar

I try to deploy and start really simple pojo in JBoss 6.1 via SAR.    My jboss-service.xml  looks like:

```
<deployment  xmlns="urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0">
    <bean name="TestBean" class="somepacage.TestBean">
        <alias>bw:name=testBean</alias>
        <install method="start"/>
        <uninstall method="stop"/>
    </bean>
</deployment>
```

POJO is just a bean with default constructor and sports public start() and stop() methods.   I see SAR picked up and deployed, and module and classloader are created and visible through jmx console.    But bean inside is completely ignored.

Do I miss something important?

tia,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out,   pojos are deployed only from files ending with:

```
*-jboss-beans.xml
```

Once name was changed,  everything worked as intendet